# Space of holomorphic functions with compact-open topology is second-countable

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, second-countable

Basically what the title says. Can anybody provide a proof that the space of holomorphic functions on an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ equipped with the compact-open topology (a.k.a. topology of compact convergence) is second countable?

According to my professor this should be true.

Comment: A good first step is to construct a metric on it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I thought the space isn't metrizable?

Comment: It does not have a translation invariant metric.

Comment: It is metrisable. It's in fact a Fréchet-Montel space, even a Fréchet-Schwartz space. It is not _normable_ (because it's an infinite-dimensional Montel space) [except for $U = \varnothing$ of course].

Comment: Consider a sequence $(K_n)$ of compact sets whose union is $U$, and define $d(f,g)=\sum_n2^{-n}\max\{1,\lVert f-g\rVert_{\infty,K_n}\}$.

Comment: I'd guess this is done in Conway's book on complex analysis.

Comment: Yes. It is in Conway's book.

Comment: Then would you use polynomials for the next step?!

Comment: Well, can you prove that you can approximate uniformly a holomorphic function on a compact set with a polynomial?

Comment: That's just using power series expansion. Right? But we gotta choose among countably many polynomials! Do we then need to show that any polynomial can be approximated via polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @HamidEnki Only if $U$ is nice enough. In general, you cannot uniformly approximate $f \in \mathscr{O}(U)$ with polynomials (that is, holomorphic polynomials) on all compact subsets of $U$. For that, $U$ must be a Runge domain.

Comment: An useful observation is that a subspace of a second countable space is itself second countable, so if you can show that the space of all continuous functions on U is second countable you'll be done.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez shouldn't your Metric have a $\min$ instead of a $\max$ ? In order to satisfy $d(f, f) = 0$